# OpenCL on rPi 400

Tags: driver, pi-400

I have an rPi 400 running Raspbian (Debian GNU/Linux 11.)

If I run `clinfo` on it, I see 0 platforms.

I have no `/etc/vendor/` directory either.

How do I run OpenCL on my rPi400?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OpenCL available for the Raspberry Pi 4.

But there is [CLVK](https://github.com/kpet/clvk) which translates the CL kernel into a Vulkan kernel.

The Vulkan driver for rPi4 is called [v3dv](https://docs.mesa3d.org/drivers/v3d.html) which can be used for this.

You need an up-to-date version of v3dv, so either build it from source, or make sure your distribution uses one that is not too old. At the time of writing: Raspberry Pi OS (Debian 11) has a Vulkan driver that is too old (missing the `VK_KHR_storage_buffer_storage_class` extension.) But Ubuntu OS 23.04 has one that will work with v3dv.

Once you have built a `libOpenCL.so` with CLVK, you can launch a CL application like this:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libOpenCL.so clinfo
```

Lastly, I must warn that currently, the v3dv Vulkan Driver lacks a lot of extensions. For instance, it cannot do fp16, nor can it do 8bit integer operations. So not all CL kernels will run on it.